# listplot and postscript

Tags: diagrams, pstricks

Is there a possibility with listplot to make lines from a point which is defined?

Example...

Fileinput:

```
-0.013,0.471
0.044,-0.294
-0.069,0.446
0.025,-0.385
0.038,-0.448
0.073,-0.365
0.375,0.045
....
```

I want to find code wich does the following....

```
\psline(1,1)(-0.013,0.471)
\psline(1,1)(0.044,-0.294)
......
```

Is there a way to do this easyly?

Update Code:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[full]{textcomp} % Euro-Zeichen etc...

\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-plot} %27.07.2012 testweise
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\def\ifinstr#1#2{%
  \def\@ifinstr##1#2##2\@nil{%
    \ifstrempty{##2}{\@secondoftwo}{\@firstoftwo}}%
  \@ifinstr#1\@@nil#2\@nil
}

\def\popleft#1#2{%
  \edef\@tmpa{#1}%
  \expandafter\@popleft\expandafter{\@tmpa}{#1}{#2}}
\def\@popleft#1#2#3{%
  \ifinstr{#1}{|}
    {\@@popleft{#2}{#3}\q@nil#1\q@stop}
    {\@@popleft{#2}{#3}\q@nil#1|\q@stop}}
\def\@@popleft#1#2\q@nil#3|#4\q@stop{\edef#1{#4}\edef#2{#3}}

\newcommand*\assignvalues[2]{\@assignvalues{#1}{#2}}
\def\@assignvalues#1#2{%
  \edef\@tmpb{#1}\edef\@tmpc{#2}%
  \popleft\@tmpb\currentvalueA
  \popleft\@tmpc\currentvalueB
  \csedef{\currentvalueA}{\currentvalueB}%
  \ifdefempty\@tmpb{}{\assignvalues\@tmpb\@tmpc}%
}
\makeatother

\FPset\tsize{0.75} % Schriftgröße
\FPset\schriftgr{0.75}
\FPset\schriftgrad{0.4} % Anderson Darling Schriftgröße
\FPset\digitz{5}


\begin{document}   

\assignvalues{xstart|xend|ystart|yend|yistart|nhlines|nvlines|nvunit|hilfsgitternetzlinien|alternativskalierung|inputf|altscale|rgg}{0|9|-0.8|4.6|0|14|10|2|5|0.35|Messdaten/statistik/rohstoffextruder.dat|1|0}
\assignvalues{dart}{loading}
\assignvalues{mbstartx|mbstepx|mbstarty|mbstepy}{1|1|1|1}
\assignvalues{bottomdesc|leftdesc|topdesc|rightdesc|lab|bcaption}{Unten|Links|Oben|Rechts|label|Bezeichnung}
\assignvalues{nvlines|nhlines|lab|mbstartx|mbstepx|hilfsgitterlinien|mbstarty|mbstepy|bcaption|bottomdesc|leftdesc}{5|4|fig:LoadingPlot|-0.1|0.1|15|-0.50|0.25|Loading Plot Rohstoff Extruder|Erste Komponente|Zweite Komponente}
\assignvalues{scalex|scaley|scaler}{1|1|1}

\assignvalues{dummyj|dummyba|dummyh|xendn|dummyq|altscale|miny|dummyu|dummybb|dummyr|dummyl|dummym|dummyb|minstarty|dummyu|dummyt|schriftgrad|gesamthl|messb|dummyd|nhlinesn|minstart|dummyr|dummybb|distmove}
{-0.600000000000000000|-0.069|-0.1|9|0.5|1|-0.448|-0.50|4.6|1.15000|1.80000|0.12000|1.8|0.25|-0.50|0|0.4|75|1|6|5|0.1|1.15000|4.6|1.000000000000000000}

\readdata{\dataA}{Messdaten/statistik/rohstoffextruder.dat}

\ifthenelse{\equal{\messb}{1}}{\message{^^JLade Datenquelle(n) für Diagramm \bcaption\space^^J}}{}
\DTLsetseparator{,}
\DTLifdbexists{table4441}{\DTLdeletedb{table4441}}{ }
\DTLloaddb[noheader,keys={wertx,werty}]{table4441}{\inputf}
\readdata{\dataA}{\inputf}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\messb}{1}}{\message{^^JEinige FP rechnungen, die durch Assignvalues ersetz worden sind..... \bcaption\space^^J}}{}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
%\begin{center}
\centering
\psset{xunit=\scalex cm,yunit=\scaley cm, runit=\scaler cm}

\pstScalePoints(1,1){\dummyba\space \dummyh\space neg \dummyba\space sub add add  \xendn\space mul \dummyq\space\altscale\space mul \space div}{\miny\space neg \dummyu\space neg \miny\space neg sub add add  \dummybb\space mul}
%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\messb}{1}}{\message{^^JZeichne Bildbereich}}{}
%
\begin{pspicture}(\xstart,\ystart)(\xend,\yend)
%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\messb}{1}}{\message{Zeichne die Gitternetzlinien für Diagramm \bcaption\space ^^J}}{}
%
\multiput(\xstart,\dummyr)(\xstart,\dummyr){\nhlines}{\psline[linecolor=black,linestyle=dashed,linewidth=0.4pt](\xstart,\yistart)(\xend,\yistart)}
\multiput(\xstart,\dummyr)(\xstart,\dummyr){\nhlines}{\psline[linecolor=black,linewidth=0.8pt](-0.1,0)(0,0.0)}
%
\multiput(\dummyl,\yistart)(\dummyl,\yistart){\nvlines}{\psline[linecolor=black,linestyle=dashed,linewidth=0.4pt](\xstart,\yistart)(\xstart,\yend)}
\multiput(\dummym,\yistart)(\dummym,\yistart){\gesamthl}{\psline[linecolor=black,linestyle=dotted,linewidth=0.4pt](\xstart,\yistart)(\xstart,\yend)}
\multiput(\dummyl,\yistart)(\dummyl,\yistart){\nvlines}{\psline[linecolor=black,linewidth=0.8pt](0,-0.1)(0,0.0)}
%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\messb}{1}}{\message{Die Gitternetzlinien für Diagramm \bcaption\space wurden fertiggestellt^^J}}{}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\messb}{1}}{\message{Beginne die Beschriftung für Diagramm \bcaption\space ^^J}}{}
%
\multido{\na=\dummyh+\minstart,\nb=0+\dummyb}{\dummyd}{\rput{0}(\nb,-0.3){\FPclip\na\na \scalebox{\schriftgrad}{\na}}}
\multido{\na=\dummyt+\dummyr,\nb=\dummyu+\minstarty}{\nhlinesn}{\rput{0}(-0.5,\na){\FPclip\nb\nb
\scalebox{\schriftgrad}{\nb}}}
\uput[0](\dummyj,-0.7){%
\scalebox{\scalex}{
\begin{tabular}{C{\xend cm}}
 \scalebox{\tsize}{\bottomdesc}  \\ 
\end{tabular}
}}
%
\uput[90](-1.3,-0.7){\rotateleft {%
\scalebox{\scaley}{
\begin{tabular}{C{\yend cm}}
 \scalebox{\tsize}{\leftdesc}  \\ 
\end{tabular}
}}} % Achsenbeschriftung y
\ifthenelse{\equal{\messb}{1}}{\message{Die Beschriftung für Diagramm \bcaption\space wurde fertig gestellt^^J}}{}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\messb}{1}}{\message{^^JZeichne die Daten von \bcaption\space ^^J}}{}


% Alter Code....
%\ifthenelse{\equal{\dart}{loading}}{
% \DTLforeach{table4441}{%
%  \wertx=wertx,\werty=werty}{
%  \FPupn{X}{\wertx}
%  \FPupn{X}{X \dummyba\space \dummyh\space neg \dummyba\space sub add add  \xendn\space mul \dummyq\space\altscale\space mul \space div}
%  \FPround\X\X\digitz
%  \FPupn{Y}{\werty}
%   \FPupn{Y}{Y \miny\space neg \dummyu\space neg \miny\space neg sub add add  \dummybb\space mul}
%   \FPupn{Xs}{\minstart\space \distmove\space mul \xendn\space mul \dummyq\space\altscale\space mul \space div}
%   \FPupn{Ys}{\dummyu\space neg \dummybb\space mul}   \psline[linecolor=blued,linestyle=dashed,linewidth=0.4pt](\Xs,\Ys)(\X,\Y)
% }
%}{}
%

% ersetzt durch Herberts neuen Code
\FPupn{Xs}{\minstart\space \distmove\space mul \xendn\space mul \dummyq\space\altscale\space mul \space div}
\FPupn{Ys}{\dummyu\space neg \dummybb\space mul}  
\makeatletter
\pslistplot[linecolor=red!50]{
   /startpoint { \Xs\space \Ys\space \tx@ScreenCoor\space moveto } def
   mark \dataA \space counttomark 2 div cvi /nData exch def 
   nData {
     startpoint \tx@ScreenCoor\space lineto
   } repeat
}
\pslistplot[plotstyle=dots]{\dataA}
% Herberts neuer Code

\ifthenelse{\equal{\dart}{screen}}{
\listplot[plotstyle=line, linewidth=1.73pt, linecolor=black,showpoints=false,dotstyle=*,dotsize=4pt]{\dataA}  % Punkte Blau 200 Grad
\listplot[plotstyle=dots, linewidth=1.73pt, linecolor=white,showpoints=true,dotstyle=*,dotsize=6pt]{\dataA}  % Punkte Blau 200 Grad
\listplot[plotstyle=dots, linewidth=1.73pt, linecolor=black,showpoints=true,dotstyle=*,dotsize=4pt]{\dataA}  % Punkte Blau 200 Grad
}{}

\ifthenelse{\equal{\dart}{loading}}{
\listplot[plotstyle=dots, linewidth=1.73pt, linecolor=black,showpoints=true,dotstyle=*,dotsize=6pt]{\dataA}  % Punkte Blau 200 Grad
\listplot[plotstyle=dots, linewidth=1.73pt, linecolor=black,showpoints=true,dotstyle=*,dotsize=4pt]{\dataA}  % Punkte Blau 200 Grad
}{}

\psline(\xstart,\yistart)(\xend,\yistart)
\psline(\xstart,\yistart)(\xstart,\yend)
\psline(\xend,\yistart)(\xend,\yend)
\psline(\xstart,\yend)(\xend,\yend)
\end{pspicture}
\caption[\bcaption]{\bcaption} 
\label{\lab}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Code, nearly reached the goal....

```
\assignvalues{xstart|xend|ystart|yend|yistart|nhlines|nvlines|nvunit|hilfsgitternetzlinien|alternativskalierung|inputf|altscale|rgg}{0|9|-0.8|4.6|0|14|10|2|5|0.35|Messdaten/statistik/rohstoffextruder.dat|1|0}
\assignvalues{dart}{loading}
\assignvalues{mbstartx|mbstepx|mbstarty|mbstepy}{1|1|1|1}
\assignvalues{bottomdesc|leftdesc|topdesc|rightdesc|lab|bcaption}{Unten|Links|Oben|Rechts|label|Bezeichnung}
\assignvalues{nvlines|nhlines|lab|mbstartx|mbstepx|hilfsgitterlinien|mbstarty|mbstepy|bcaption|bottomdesc|leftdesc}{5|4|fig:LoadingPlot|-0.1|0.1|15|-0.50|0.25|Loading Plot Rohstoff Extruder|Erste Komponente|Zweite Komponente}
\assignvalues{scalex|scaley|scaler}{1|1|1}

    \assignvalues{dummyj|dummyba|dummyh|xendn|dummyq|altscale|miny|dummyu|dummybb|dummyr|dummyl|dummym|dummyb|minstarty|dummyu|dummyt|schriftgrad|gesamthl|messb|dummyd|nhlinesn|minstart|dummyr|dummybb|distmove}{-0.600000000000000000|-0.069|-0.1|9|0.5|1|-0.448|-0.50|4.6|1.15000|1.80000|0.12000|1.8|0.25|-0.50|0|0.4|75|1|6|5|0.1|1.15000|4.6|1.000000000000000000}

\FPupn{Xs}{\minstart\space \distmove\space mul \xendn\space mul \dummyq\space\altscale\space mul \space div}
\FPupn{Ys}{\dummyu\space neg \dummybb\space mul}  
\makeatletter
\pslistplot[linecolor=red!50]{
   /startpoint { \Xs\space \Ys\space \tx@ScreenCoor\space moveto } def
   mark \dataA \space counttomark 2 div cvi /nData exch def 
   nData {
     \tx@ScreenCoor\space \miny\space neg \dummyu\space neg \miny\space neg sub add add  \dummybb\space mul
     exch \tx@ScreenCoor\space \dummyba\space \dummyh\space neg \dummyba\space sub add add  \xendn\space mul \dummyq\space\altscale\space mul \space div exch
     startpoint \tx@ScreenCoor\space lineto
   } repeat
}
%\makeatother
\pslistplot[plotstyle=dots]{\dataA}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\pslistplot` can handle any kind of PostScript functions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\def\data{
-0.013 0.471
0.044 -0.294
-0.069 0.446
0.025 -0.385
0.038 -0.448
0.073 -0.365
0.375 0.045}
\begin{document}
\begin{psgraph}(0,0)(-0.5,-1)(1,1){5cm}{5cm}
\makeatletter
\pslistplot[linecolor=red!50]{
   /startpoint { 1 1 \tx@ScreenCoor\space moveto } def % define a function for moving to 1 1 in screen coordinates
   mark \data \space counttomark 2 div cvi /nData exch def % count the number of data pairs and save it in nData
   nData { % repeat loop over nData
     startpoint % move to startpoint (1,1)
     \tx@ScreenCoor\space % transform the last two x y values into screen coordinates
     lineto % draw a line to these corrdinates
   } repeat % end of repeat
}
\pslistplot[plotstyle=dots]{\data}
\end{psgraph}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hallo Herbert, schaut gut aus, geht aber nicht. Ich antworte wegen dem Zeichenlimit auf mein eigenes Posting. Ich weiß genau, wo der Fehler liegt und dafür kann man hier aufgrund meiner Angaben nichts, sie waren leider unvollständig. Ich muß den X und Y Wert auch manipulieren können, bevor ich ihn an pslistplot übergebe....das habe ich in der Ursprungslösung ebenfalls gemacht. Vielleicht ist mein gesamtes Vorgehen stark überdenkenswürdig aber ich arbeite daran erstens immer mehr der zugrundeliegenden Mechanismen von pstricks und postscript zu verstehen (Mehr schlecht als recht) um dann ....

Comment: dynamische Diagramme erstellen zu können. Ein Problem, welches du 2009 *QUELLE* mit max und min hattest kann man über das datatool lösen....Ich hab im Code angeführt, wo es hackt. und zwar habe ich im Datatool Abschnitt eine Zeile stehen, die die X-Werte aus der Datei nochmals bearbeitet: \FPupn{X}{X \dummyba\space \dummyh\space neg \dummyba\space sub add add  \xendn\space mul \dummyq\space\altscale\space mul \space div} und die fehlt, was natürlich dazu führt, dass er die variablen X-Koordinaten falsch setzt, die Ausgangspunkte habe ich schon korrekt geesetzt und ein leerzeichen mit \space ..

Comment: erzwungen.... warum bin ich eigentlich nicht mit login eingeloggt... ich hol das gleich nach....

Comment: @user1558112: You should ask or write comments in English. This one of the policy here. I know Herbert is from Germany but nevertheless he will understand you.

Comment: Sorry, should I to the translation on the comments here I have already posted or should I do this for the future?

Comment: @herbert: maybe a short description about the postscriptcode will be enough, to do it on my own....

Comment: @user1558112: see my edit. `\tx@ScreenCoor` is defined in `pstricks.tex`

Comment: @Herbert, I thinke, that i understand your code. unfortunately i dont know how to take the actual row on the stack und then i should know, which value i have to process. It seems to me, that there is no way to identify x and y values, even the order tells me when i have to calculate..... the first value is the last on in the datalist, I dont unterstand this behavior....

Comment: Ok, I'm sure, i dont understand the code.... it seems, that you only take ALL values on the stack to count them, in order to know how to oft to run throu the loop....

Comment: on the stack is _always_ x y x y ... So you really know what's the next data entry

Comment: the odd ones are the x...

Comment: `y` is always on top of the stack

Comment: exch calculating exch....?!?

Comment: the first line in the loop I tryd is...

Comment: exch \tx@ScreenCoor\space \dummyba\space \dummyh\space neg \dummyba\space sub add add  \xendn\space mul \dummyq\space\altscale\space mul \space div exch

Comment: `3 mul exch 4 mul exch` will multiply `y*3` and `x*4` but with the same order on the stack (x y)

Comment: You are great. I am a fool.... Now in know, why you use psgraph, i tryd to aviod it....

Comment: Hm, it looks good, but i think there are some unusual behavior.... the code seems to be not äquaivalent.... I will search for my errors....

Comment: I thought, thats it, but the lines go out of the diagramm, hm, why, I dont know and the lines seem not to take the correct koordinates.....

Comment: I will add my script to the thread....

Comment: Anybody an Explantion, why the script with the datatool package fails?

Comment: create a _minimal example_ and do not post such a bombastic file ...

Comment: it seens for me at the moment, that der is an incompatibilität between pst-plot and datatool. You cant use datatool code inside pstricks an the very end of the code, espession if multiput and multido us used....

Comment: ok. I will do an minimum example

Comment: still working on minimum example....

Comment: I have found the error, I am sure, you will not believe it.... i would like to send the code and the explanation....., if you put a \message{Info} which comes befor the first line of datatool, (DTLforeach) then the complette picture will be not on the definied coordinates. IF you make comments to the message commands, everyrthing is fine, also, if you definde pnode(1,1){A} (Dummycommand) then everything is ok. Its ONLY the special combination of the message command + datatool, which causes the error....

Comment: what I learned in 40 years of programming is: the time you need for locating an error is inversely proportional to the quality of the error ... :-)  or in short: if you don't find the problem after 30 minutes then go into the kitchen and take a cup of tea or coffee ...

Comment: lol, thanks, you are absolutly right. But This problem cames, as I begann to message my output to log, in order to find my own mistakes much faster.. lol....

Comment: @herbert: one more question for you: Your solution does not draw point to point, it does not stop at the point as i have expected.... is this postscriptspezific?

Comment: sorry, do not understand what you mean with point to point

Comment: @user1558112 Please do not use the comment feature as a chat. Asking details etc. and getting answers would be ok, but please delete the comments afterwards, if they are just for you but don't add value to the answer. The answer could be extended by ideas from the comments. Finally, there should only few comments remain, if at all. Herbert, it would be nice if you would also remove comments, or move into the answer.